# Deploying snapshot sources - Is it possible ? It increments build number

Tags: maven, deployment, snapshot, nexus, maven-3

guys I don't know what could be wrong, but I'm deploying snapshot and sources with `gpg:sign-and-deploy-file`, but the sources name does always have the value of the following buildnumber. Like artifact-timestamp-1.jar and artifact-timestamp-2-sources.jar

so that if I then have a snapshot dependency, it is looking for artifact-timestamp-2.jar instead of artifact-timestamp-1.jar

I'm not using any build number plugin etc., the pom definitions for this artifact is having only credentials.

I also don't use SCM...

IS THERE ANY WORKAROUND FOR DEPLOYING SNAPSHOT SOURCES ? Cause obviously it is not allowed be design.

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/b2F5Ju1s)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Maven 3.0 and unfortunately `sources` and `javadoc` properties was added to `maven-deploy-plugin v.2.6` and `maven-gpg-plugin v.1.3` ... But Maven 3.0 was using `maven-gpg-plugin v.1.2` and `maven-deploy-plugin v.2.5`

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug in gpg plugin. As a workaround you can try to use gpg:sign in combination with deploy:deploy.

Comment: gpg is using deploy itself, If I use deploy instead of gpg, the result is the same. Maven doesn't let you deploy snapshot sources by design.

Comment: Why is this not allowed by design? I have the same problem here as I want to debug my internal projects on the sources...

Comment: I am using the hudson deploy plugin with deploying to nexus sonatype btw